# How would I use a if statement in python, if I have to ask the user to choose one option out of the described dictionary?

Tags: python

```
color = {"1":"Violet","2":"Indigo","3":"Blue","4":"Green","5":"Yellow","6":"Orange","7":"Red"}

print ("Select your choice")
print (color)
color1 = input ("Select the first color: ")

for color1 in color:
    if color1 != color:
        print ("Please choose the correct option!")
```

Comment: Essentially what I want to do is to ask the user to select an option for a color and use if statement to print a message based on what they choose.

Ex. If someone chooses 1. it should print "Please choose the next option". If someone enters a option that isn't available (like 10) it should say "This option isn't available!". Also, I think I would have to use a while loop somewhere as well. Sorry, I'm very new to code and transationing from Hospitality industry due to Covid. Appericiate the help!

Answer (score 2):

```
if color1 in color:
    col = color[color1]
    print(col)
```

Prints the color (for example: Red), if the color's number is in the list/dict

```
if color1 in color.values():
    #ETC
```

Prints the color (for example: Red), if the color's name is in the list/dict

Thanks for [Kyle Alm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9237842/kyle-alm) for clarification. `for color1 in color: if color1 != color: print ("Please choose the correct option!")` is not needed there!

Comment: This works, but for clarification, OP does not need the last for-loop. This goes immediately after the input() line, without "for color1 in color:"